# Umbraco Sub Navigation Not Showing

Tags: xslt, navigation, umbraco

I have umbarco sub navigation code XSLt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:tagsLib="urn:tagsLib" xmlns:BlogLibrary="urn:BlogLibrary" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets tagsLib BlogLibrary ">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- The fun starts here -->
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
    <li>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If no child page, it should show ancestor page link.
But now its showing empty. If it has child page its showing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it is me, but I don't see any code for showing the ancestor page. Or is that your question, that you don;t know how to write that code?
Also I think you want to display the parent-item instead of the ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

Since umbracoNaviHide will be an attribute in the XML, try testing for

> string(@umbracoNaviHide) != '1'